# VirtualBox Custom Screen Resolution Issues

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Alright I got tasked with making a standard development environment for android development for the team. I am trying to get more out of the VM IE: being able to full screen and actually having it scale up to the screen size.

I tried all the normal methods. Installed Guest additions / used VBoxManage.exe but none of it seems to be working.

The VM has crunchbang Linux installed with nvidia drivers installed. For what resolution I am running at its clear but its not going to do well for a dev environment.

Anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it following this Tutorial:

[How to set Widescreen 16:9 resolution in VirtualBox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFssIDbQwCM)

Comment: So what did you do wrong? How did you you find what it was ? Was there a tricky part, where the tutorial helped you? If you don't provide any more info, your question and answer are not helpful for anyone. It's great that you solved your problem and accomplished your task, but you are not helping anyone by just logging your progress..

Answer (score 0):

**If someone encountered this problem in 2023, there is a gist that worked for me in the KDE Desktop environment using VirtualBox:**

First of all, enter "xrandr" in the terminal to list all available screen resolutions:

```
$ xrandr
```

Note the name of the output that corresponds to your monitor, For example,
VGA-1 or Virtual1 (For Virtual Box).

Then enter this:

```
ro@debian-main:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Take the output from that and put in the terminal:

```
ro@debian-main:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then enter these commands:

```
ro@debian-main:~$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
ro@debian-main:~$ xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 60
```

Screen resolution will change.

Enter xrandr in the terminal to see available screen resolutions.

```
ro@debian-main:~$ xrandr
```

And you will see your screen resolution there.

P.S. If your screen resolution returns to the same resolution try to turn off the background service "KScreen 2" in the
Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Background Services.

**Original gist:** https://gist.github.com/RasulOs/db7717ec6eaa85fcd20853116696d7d7